# C# How I can retrieve this information?

Tags: c#, html, winforms

On the HTML Page I have something like that

```
<table class="information">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="name">Name:</td>
<td><a href="example.com">John</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
....
</tbody>
</table>
```

How I can retrieve the name (there are other information too but in my example I wrote only name)?

Notes: HTML has more than one table

I tried this

```
foreach (HtmlElement item in wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table"))
{
    if (item.OuterHtml.Contains("information"))
    {
        ... //Here i don't know how to continue
    }
}
```

Comment: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) FTW!

Comment: +1 for HTML Agility Pack. Underneath it uses XPath to query the HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlElementCollection tData = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("td");

                foreach (HtmlElement td in tData)
                {
                    string name = "";
                    if (td.GetAttribute("classname") == "name")
                    {
                        name = td.InnerText;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Rosana this exactly what I needed but there is a problem.. Your answer will give result "Name:" but I want the result to be "John"... I tried to modify it and write td.NextSibling.InnerText to take the inner text of next element but there is error

Comment: Then try this way - 
First find this table control
<table class="information">
using the same method as above.

Then iterate through the <td> controls and look for <a>
as your example there is only one <a> tag inside the <td> tag.
So you can easily get the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='information']");
var td = table.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='name']");

Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
```

or

```
var text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
    .First(td => td.Attributes["class"] != null && td.Attributes["class"].Value == "name")
    .InnerText;
```

Comment: Can you help me install it? When i unzip it i have these folders.. Net20, Net40, Net40-client, Net45, sl3-wp, sl4, sl4-windowsphone71, sl5 and winrt45.... which one to use to add it as reference?

Comment: @Alkis select the platform you use to reference. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it is free and quite good library to work with html sources.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is cool but I prefer ScrapySharp (http://nuget.org/packages/ScrapySharp). It is build over HtmlAgilityPack but also providers CSS selectors support.

Comment: How to install them? how to use them?

Comment: Download binaries from page above. Add them to references. For using: look at documentation.

Comment: i cannot find any documentation to scrapysharp?